# Overcommit gem is preventing a commit

Tags: rubygems, ruby-overcommit

I have installed a ruby on rails application that was running on another machine that used the [overcommit gem](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit).  I do not want to use the overcommit gem.  When I try to do a commit e.g.

```
git commit -m 'Add something'
```

I have the error message

```
This repository contains hooks installed by Overcommit, but the `overcommit` gem is not installed.
Install it with `gem install overcommit`.
```

If I install the overcommit gem, I still receive the same message. I have tried:

```
overcommit --uninstall
```

but still get the same error message when I try to do a commit.

How do I fix this so I can do commits?

Comment: What does `overcommit --list-hooks` show you?  Are you sure you ran the `uninstall` command from the same repo in which you are trying to make a commit?  Also, did you try restarting your Git Bash, just in case it needs to be refreshed?

Comment: If I try to do 'overcommit --list-hooks' I get 'overcommit: command not found'.  I did run the uninstall command from same repo.   What is the simplest way to restart Git Bash, i.e. do I need to reboot my machine or is there an easier way?

Comment: For restarting the bash, just closing and reopening it should be sufficient.  I'm surprised that now `overcommit` is not found.  If so, then what happens if you run `overcommit --uninstall` again?

Comment: After rebooting my machine, I received a different error message and some different response to those described above. I have now raised an issue, https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/issues/571, which has some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as an issue on the [overcommit github site](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/issues/571#issuecomment-379513672).

It looks like it is a problem with a corruption of my installation. In order to solve this, I cloned a fresh copy of the master repository to my machine, and manually added changes from the corrupted repository. This fixed the problem, but unfortunately gives little insight to the actual caused.